# Checkbox control to enable other controls on form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a form for searching a database inside my application, and I only want to add a control's input as a `WHERE` if its enabled. The best method I have found is a set of checkboxes next to each set of controls to enable them.

[image]

Now, I can add the logic to the `CheckedChanged` of each checkbox, but I have several different types of controls- textboxes, datepickers, comboboxes. So they would have to be done individually- leading to quite a bit of boilerplate code.

```
private void ChartCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassComboBox.Enabled = ChartCheckBox.Checked;
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: +1 for the first question I've seen with a picture - makes the question very easy to understand.

Comment: @MichaelRodrigues Answering questions all day makes you appreciate the art of crafting a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this using a [composite control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207.aspx) - it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Looks good, I can hook my checkboxes in the control and then grab properties off of them in the main form.

Comment: It's really neat - a bit more work up front but well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just include a particular field's WHERE clause if the length of the text in that field is > 0?  e.g.   `if (txtArtist.Text.Length > 0) { ...`

That way you can get rid of the check boxes and the form will be more self-maintaining...

Comment: It's not simply textboxes. I have checkboxes, comboboxes, datepickers. If someone checks and then unchecks a checkbox, do they want to search  for *not* things matching that description, or did they mean to not check it at all?

Comment: I would have  a checkBox for  "Is Not".   I usually structure things like this as  [Field] [Is | Is Not | Contains | etc. ] [Value]